# ClassCastException:com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I'm new in developing maven application and deploy to google app engine.
i'm using `appengine 1.9.0` and `eclipse kepler 4.3`

However when I try to run, I got an error and according to this [blog](http://chstrongjavablog.blogspot.com/2012/05/some-errors-solutions-down-way.html) by chris, It suggested to remove this jar.

```
appengine-api-labs 
appengine-api-stubs 
appengine-testing
```

I already removed it in the libraries and tried maven clean but the error still appear.
below is my libraries.

[image: libraries]

below is the full console error:

```
WARNING: failed _ah_ServeBlobFilter: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal
3 20, 2014 2:34:57 午前 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@87ec13{/,C:\Users\Annette\Desktop\WebCaller\src\main\webapp}
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.init(ServeBlobFilter.java:55)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:250)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:305)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:97)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
```

can anyone point it out? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I took the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Removing the appengine-api-stubs and appengine-testing
2. On Properties, and Google > App Engine, I made sure to select the default "App Engine - 1.9.1"
3. On properties build path, I removed all JARs related to the GAE v1.9.1 and instead added the GAE library from "Add Library"

Surprisingly, my localhost deployment worked eventhough I had appengine-api-labs on my WEB-INF/lib.

Lastly, my WEB-INF/lib contains the following:

- appengine-agent.jar
- appengine-agentimpl.jar
- appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.1.jar
- appengine-api-labs-1.9.1.jar
- appengine-api-labs.jar
- appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
- appengine-endpoints.jar
- appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.1.jar

I hope that helps. It worked for me and chances are it might work for you.

Comment: This is not a solution for people who actually use App Engine/datastore unit tests in their projects - unit tests, of course, being a good idea.

Comment: I use those libs for important data conversion functions, so it is a shame that they break the server.

Comment: One crazy thing. I've removed appengine-stubs from buildpath and the problem still happening. After deleting them it solved.

Comment: I faced this problem migrating my project to use maven, for some reason I had the jars appengine-api-stubs and appengine-testing in the folder "src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib". I deleted all jar in this folder and everything worked after that

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to make sure that you have only one version of appengine-testing.jar on your classpath that corresponds to your App Engine SDK, *and* you don't have appengine-tools-api.jar on your classpath or in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

If you meet these conditions and still have this error, remove appengine-testing.jar from your classpath *and* from `/WEB-INF/lib` if you have it there, and then add it back to your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I tried the solution provided by Andrei Volgin but it didn't work for me. Then I **removed** *appengine-api-stubs.jar* from the `/WEB-INF/lib` and the bug is fixed.

To resume, I **have** *appengine-api-libs* and *appengine-api-testing* in my `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. And I have **only** the *appengine-api-testing* into the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Add the latest dependency and clean the build and run again it should work in local. As I avail to resolve the same problem.

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.64</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.64</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this exact problem. With maven I added test to all my test-related dependencies to fix the problem. I presume it's  just another way to avoid conflicting jars in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you wanna make sure that you add  **test scope** to the jars which you are deleting from the **Target** folder.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.23</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```